# Make a scatter plot from two lists

Tags: plotting

I have two lists of values

```
xx = {0.1, 0.3, 0.35, 0.57, 0.88, 1.0}
yy = {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 7.8, 9.0, 12.2}
```

I want to make a scatter plot (list plot) with xx as x axis and yy as y axis. The help document on ListPlot tells me I have to use

```
ListPlot[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}]
```

How do I create something like

```
ListPlot[{{0.1, 1.2}, {0.3, 3.5}, ...}]
```

from xx and yy? Thank you.

Comment: Change square brackets `[...]` to braces `{...}` in the definitions of `xx` and `yy`. Check the documentation for [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) and/or [Thread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html)

Comment: @kguler Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First off, your syntax is incorrect; you need to use braces to define your lists:

```
xx = {0.1, 0.3, 0.35, 0.57, 0.88, 1.0};
yy = {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 7.8, 9.0, 12.2};
```

You can then create a 2x6 matrix from `xx` and `yy`, and transpose it to get a 6x2 matrix of pairs, which is the correct format:

```
data = Transpose@{xx, yy};
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great, Thank you. BTW: why did you write Transpose@{xx, yy} instead of Transpose[{xx, yy}]?

Comment: @PatrickLi, because they mean exactly the same thing. Look up `Prefix` in the documentation center.

Comment: @RunnyKine Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

If you have

```
xx = {0.1, 0.3, 0.35, 0.57, 0.88, 1.0}
yy = {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 7.8, 9.0, 12.2}
```

you can do

```
Thread[{xx, yy}]
```

which gives

```
{{0.1, 1.2}, {0.3, 3.5}, {0.35, 4.5}, {0.57, 7.8}, {0.88, 9.}, {1., 
  12.2}}
```

and then

```
ListPlot[{{0.1`, 1.2`}, {0.3`, 3.5`}, {0.35`, 4.5`}, {0.57`, 
   7.8`}, {0.88`, 9.`}, {1.`, 12.2`}}]
```

[image]

So

```
ListPlot[Thread[{xx, yy}]]
```

is the answer.

Kind regards

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, and thank you for contributing. But, how is it different from the other, accepted [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21886/)?

Comment: I used Thread instead of Transpose. So you are right, when you say, the result is exactly the same. It's just a little different solution.