# Plot table versus table

Tags: plotting

I have two tables like:

```
nex1 = Table[l3*10^3/4*10^14, {l3, 1, 30, 1}];
nex2= Table[l4, {l4, 1, 30, 1}];
```

How can I plot nex1 versus nex2 so that nex1 is x axis and nex2 is y axis (not distinct plot of this tables in one plot).

Comment: `Transpose[{nex1, nex2}]`.

Comment: @Kuba I wonder if there is a duplicate around. Although the question is easily answered, it might be quite useful for future beginners, so perhaps keeping it might be beneficial...

Comment: @YvesKlett Don't know if suitable but it is for example here: [Good MMA examples / Transpose and dimensions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5478)

Comment: @YvesKlett [a proper duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21884/5478)

Comment: @Kuba good one! Cannot vote anymore though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the two tables in one single list of couples of points, by using a new `Table` function. Then you can plot the created list using `ListPlot`

```
nex1 = Table[l3*10^3/4*10^14, {l3, 1, 30, 1}];
nex2 = Table[l4, {l4, 1, 30, 1}];
Table[{nex1[[i]], nex2[[i]]}, {i, 1, 30}];
ListPlot[%]
```