# Making a plot from three lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have data like

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

and

y<sub>1</sub> = [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

and

y<sub>2</sub> = [0, 10, 11.5, 12.5. 13.5, 14.5]

I want to plot y<sub>1</sub>} and y<sub>2</sub>} as a function of x on one plot and then draw a vertical line at x = 12 like a Kronecker delta.

How can I do this?

Comment: Would you please present your data in *Mathematica* format, i.e. as a list delimited by curly braces `{  }`? Normally, `Transpose@{x,y1}` would give you a dataset you could plot using `ListPlot`, as was pointed out to you in [your previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69130/27951). However, your data sets have different lengths, so that wouldn't work. Do you really have to deal with different-length lists?

Comment: Your data is inconsistent. You have 9 x values, and only 8 y1 values. I can't read y2. Any way, check `ListLinePlot` and check `Show` to combine. And check `Line` to make line.

Comment: @MarcoB no i  can do my work by equal length data

Comment: @MarcoB how plot this?x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and y(1)=[0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17] and y(2)=[0,10,11.5,12.5.13.5,14.5,15.2,16] and a vertical line at x=12

Comment: @EhsanF Your sets are still of different length; `y2` is too short by one. Also, lists are enclosed by curly brances in MMA, e.g. `x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`. Try `ListLinePlot@Transpose@{x1, y1}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your example is ill-considered, but the following does what you ask.

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
y1 = {0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};
y2 = {0, 10, 11.5, 12.5 .13 .5, 14.5};

ListLinePlot[{y1, y2},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, Automatic},
  GridLines -> {{12}, None}]
```

[image: plot]

Now, let's look at a more realistic case.

```
SeedRandom[42]; x = RandomSample[Range[15], 9] // Sort
```

> `{1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15}`

```
y1 = {0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
y2 = {0, 10, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5};
```

Then the data can be prepared for plotting with

```
data = MapThread[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}} &, {x, y1, y2}] // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{{1, 0}, {3, 11}, {7, 12}, {9, 13}, {10, 14}, {12, 15}, {13, 16}, {14, 17}, 
>   {15, 18}}, 
>  {{1, 0}, {3, 10}, {7, 11.5}, {9, 12.5}, {10, 13.5}, {12, 14.5}, {13, 15.5}, 
>   {14, 16.5}, {15, 17.5}}}
> ```

and the plot can be made with

```
ListLinePlot[data, GridLines -> {{12}, None}]
```

[image: plot]