# Apply ListPlot to various data sets

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Assume that I have data in the form:

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3}, {10, 10, 10}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 20}}}
```

I want to plot

```
ListPlot[{Thread[{list[[1, 1]], list[[1, 2]]}],Thread[{list[[2, 1]], list[[2, 2]]}]}]
```

Are there smarter way doing this?

This

```
ListPlot[
 Table[Thread[{list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]]}], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
 ]
```

is working. What are the alternatives?

Comment: `ListPlot[Transpose[list, {1, 3, 2}]]`?

Comment: I'd use `ListPlot[Transpose /@ list]`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Make a scatter plot from two lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21884/27951), [Plot column 1 against list of columns in column 2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66866/27951). Also more in general, take a look at: [(Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/27951)